# Using the ID of an element to get one of its two classes? JS

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have an element with an ID and two classes (let's call them class A and B).  You know the ID, and want to get all of the other elements that share class A, but not class B.  Not all of these elements have two class names, some of them only have class A.  Using Javascript, how can I make sure I get the proper class name when calling them using the ID of the original element, so that I get the class A elements and not class B?

Comment: You may want to go through this - https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById( 'test' );

/* to get all classes of the element */
var classList = element.className.split(' '); 

/* 
 * Say class A is in classList[0] and class B in classList[1],
 * select all elements which have class classList[0] but not class classList[1] */
var classToShow = document.querySelectorAll('.'+classList[0]+':not(.'+classList[1]+')' );

/* loop through the selected list to log each element in console */
for( var i = 0; i < classToShow.length; i++ ) {
        console.log(classToShow[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Or to keep things simpler:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.A:not(.B)');
```